# resize div depending on its child div

Tags: css

i would like to build some popup which contains some sub_div. the problem is that when i resize   my window in my popup stay some blank space. I made an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qd5kbxc7/

```
    <div id="all">
        <div id="sub_all"></div>
        <div id="sub_all"></div>
        <div id="sub_all"></div>
        <div id="sub_all"></div>
        <div id="sub_all"></div>
    </div>

#all {
    background:#ccc;
    width: auto;  
    display:table;

}

#sub_all {
    background:#ff0000;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;

}
```

so when you resize to smaller size there sometimes large empty space in the "#all div". How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: your jsfiddle has a different mark up to sample?

Comment: I've made a slightly [Edited](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/qd5kbxc7/2/) version of your 'pop up', but you haven't really explained your issue to see what you want done?

Comment: My problem is: when u resize the window/popup it stays sometime large empty gray space, I wishactually that however i resize everytime the gray div has the same width like the content/children div without empty space

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a table layout for the parent div, you should use the display:table-cell for the child divs. This will give you an equal spacing by default for any amount of children.

See jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/83gdw0uq/

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
    <div class="sub_all"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#all {
    background:#ccc;
    width: 100%;  
    display:table;
    border-spacing: 10px 5px;   /*first parameter is horizontal spacing / second is vertical spacing*/
}

.sub_all {
    background:#ff0000;
    display:table-cell;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: the number of divs is variable between 1 - 12

Comment: Ok. I better understand what you want now. See my edited answer.

Comment: totally wrong? where is the float left. When u resize the div get hidden

Comment: You don't need float left in this case. The child divs are now displayed as table-cell so they line up horizontally as columns in the parent div. What do you mean the div gets hidden? Did you click on my jsfiddle link? If you change the parent width, nothing gets hidden.

Comment: yes i dont want a static width , i need this popup for also mobile devices, it must be auto

Comment: Ok. I just put 700px there for testing so you could play with it and see that it changes. You can simply put width: 100% and the parent div will take up the full width of it's parent (or the screen if it is the top level container).

Comment: doesnt change nothing